# AngularJs How can I use one controller methods, variables in other controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers like below. I want to use first controller methods/variables in other controller

```
app.controller("createController", ["$scope",
 function ($scope)
 {
  $scope.i = 0;
  $scope.changeEstimateStatus = function()
  {
    console.log('changeEstimateStatus');
  };
 }]);


 app.controller("editController", ["$scope",
 function ($scope)
 {
    //here how can I access 'i' variable of createController
 }]);
```

Comment: How are the controllers related? Parent/child - separate pages? Give more info!\

Comment: seems like the place to use a service which has the variable i and then inject it to the controllers

Comment: Seperate pages..please suggest without using $rootScope

Comment: seems like the place to use a service which has the variable i and then inject it to the controllers –  getting console error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a shared service:

```
app.service("mySharedService", [function() {
    var _x = null;

    return {
        setX: function(val) { _x = val },
        getX: function() { return _x }
    }
}]);
```

Then inject into your controller:

```
app.controller("createController", ["$scope","mySharedService", function($scope, mySharedService) {

    $scope.i = mySharedService.getX(); //get
    mySharedService.setX(3); //set
}]);
```

Comment: Thnx alot for your valuable information tyme. If I have more methods & variables, please suggest any other solution...

Answer (score 0):

use one of this:

1.you can use  serveice and put common function to that service and access that function to all controlller.

```
app.service('MyService', function() {
     this.changeEstimateStatus = function()
      {
        console.log('changeEstimateStatus');
      };
});

   app.controller("createController", ["$scope",MyService,
     function ($scope,MyService)
     {
      $scope.i = 0;
     MyService.changeEstimateStatus ();
     }]);


     app.controller("editController", ["$scope",   app.controller("createController", ["$scope",$rootScope,
     function ($scope,$rootScope)
     {
      $scope.i = 0;
      MyService.changeEstimateStatus ();

     }]);
```

2.you can store that function in $rootscope object.and then access that function to all controlller.

like:

```
app.controller("createController", ["$scope",$rootScope,
 function ($scope,$rootScope)
 {
  $scope.i = 0;

 }]);


 app.controller("editController", ["$scope",$rootScope,
 function ($scope,$rootScope)
 {
    $rootScope.changeEstimateStatus ();
 }]);
```

but 2nd option is not a good aproach.

Comment: I agree about using a service. It'd be nice to know why though. In my opinion it's better to use a service because then you've got to explicitly import that dependency where you need it. If you use the root scope that method will be available everywhere.

Comment: @BenCr A service is always the correct place to put code that should be shared among multiple controllers, which is exactly what OP wants. $rootScope should be avoided whenever possible, because it's shared with EVERY piece of the app, while a service can be injected only where needed.

Comment: Is that not exactly what I said? The point I was making is that just saying "this isn't a good approach" without telling someone why doesn't make for a high quality SO answer.

Comment: You should *never* write methods that are automatically available everywhere, because then you might trip on them unexpectedly. It's the exact same reason you shouldn't use global variables in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the common functionality (changeEstimateStatus) into a service.  Rather than one controller depending on the other, both controllers depend on the service.

```
app.service('estimateService', function() {

  this.changeEstimateStatus = function()  {
    console.log('changeEstimateStatus');
  };

});
    app.controller("createController", ["$scope","estimateService",
 function ($scope, estimateService)
 {
  $scope.i = 0;
  $scope.changeEstimateStatus = function()
  {
    estimateService.changeEstimateStatus(); //delegate to the service
  };
 }]);


 app.controller("editController", ["$scope", "estimateService"
 function ($scope, estimateService)
 {
    $scope.changeEstimateStatus = function()
  {
    estimateService.changeEstimateStatus(); //delegate to the service
  };
 }]);
```

Another option is to use $rootScope, but using services is not as brittle to change.